# SQL Server, self-referential data, how do I add a constraint for this

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Imagine I have the following structure:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE (
    MemberId INT,
    ProductId INT,
    GlobalProductId INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (MemberId, ProductId));
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (1, 1, NULL);--this is my "global product"
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (2, 1, NULL);--this is okay
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (2, 2, 1);--this is okay
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (2, 3, 2);--this should fail
SELECT * FROM @Products;
```

The rule I want to enforce is that MemberId = 1 holds global products and all other MemberIds hold normal products.  A set of normal products can be linked to a single global product.

So I want the ability for a Member's Product to be linked to a Global Product, i.e. there would be a foreign key constraint that if the GlobalProductId isn't NULL then there should exist a ProductId that matches the GlobalProductId where the MemberId = 1.

In my example above I have one global product with a ProductId = 1.  Then I create three normal products:

- the first has no global product;
- the second is linked to the single global product I created earlier (then I could link further products to the same global product);
- the third should fail as I have linked it to a global product that doesn't exist, i.e. this script will return nothing:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM @Products WHERE MemberId = 1 AND ProductId = 2;
  ```

I can see that the simplest solution would be to create a new table to hold nothing but Global Products.  The problem with this approach is that I have a whole set of routines to load, update, delete data from the Product table and a second set of routines to perform calculations, etc. from the same table.  If I were to introduce a new "Global Products" table then I would have to duplicate dozens of UDFs to achieve this and my code would become much more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a computed column that's fixed as `1` and then add a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    MemberId INT,
    ProductId INT,
    GlobalProductId INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (MemberId, ProductId),
    GlobalMemberId AS 1 PERSISTED,
    FOREIGN KEY (GlobalMemberId,GlobalProductID)
        references Products (MemberId,ProductID)
    );
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1, 1, NULL);--this is my "global product"
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (2, 1, NULL);--this is okay
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (2, 2, 1);--this is okay
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (2, 3, 2);--this should fail
SELECT * FROM Products;
```

This produces these results:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "`FK__Products__7775B2CE`". The conflict occurred in database "`abc`", table "`dbo.Products`".
>
> The statement has been terminated.

```
MemberId    ProductId   GlobalProductId GlobalMemberId
----------- ----------- --------------- --------------
1           1           NULL            1
2           1           NULL            1
2           2           1               1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_GlobalProductId 
CHECK (GlobalProductId IS NULL AND MemberId = 1 
       OR GlobalProductId IS NOT NULL AND MemberId != 1);
```

and a `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT fk_SelfProducts
FOREIGN KEY (GlobalProductId )
REFERENCES Products (ProductId)
```

Comment: Is this meant to be a joke?  That does nothing to help as it just enforces a rule that there must be no global product or it must have an Id of 1.  As soon as I add a second global product I would need to go back and add this to my constraint??!!